# How to create a conditional dummy in R?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have a dataframe of time series data with daily observations of temperatures. I need to create a dummy variable that counts each day that has temperature above a threshold of 5C. This would be easy in itself, but an additional condition exists: counting starts only after ten consecutive days above the threshold occurs. Here's an example dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(date = seq(365), 
         temp = -30 + 0.65*seq(365) - 0.0018*seq(365)^2 + rnorm(365))
```

I think I got it done, but with too many loops for my liking. This is what I did:

```
df$dummyUnconditional <- 0
df$dummyHead <- 0
df$dummyTail <- 0

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    if(df$temp[i] > 5){
        df$dummyUnconditional[i] <- 1
    }
}

for(i in 1:(nrow(df)-9)){
    if(sum(df$dummyUnconditional[i:(i+9)]) == 10){
        df$dummyHead[i] <- 1
    }
}

for(i in 9:nrow(df)){
    if(sum(df$dummyUnconditional[(i-9):i]) == 10){
        df$dummyTail[i] <- 1
    }
}

df$dummyConditional <- ifelse(df$dummyHead == 1 | df$dummyTail == 1, 1, 0)
```

Could anyone suggest simpler ways for doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a base R option using `rle`:

```
df$dummy <- with(rle(df$temp > 5), rep(as.integer(values & lengths >= 10), lengths))
```

---

**Some explanation:** The task is a classic use case for the run length encoding (`rle`) function, imo. We first check if the value of `temp` is greater than 5 (creating a logical vector) and apply `rle` on that vector resulting in:

```
> rle(df$temp > 5)
#Run Length Encoding
#  lengths: int [1:7] 66 1 1 225 2 1 69
#  values : logi [1:7] FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE ...
```

Now we want to find those cases where the `values` is `TRUE` (i.e. temp is greater than 5) and where at the same time the `lengths` is greater than 10 (i.e. at least ten consecutive `temp`values are greater than 5). We do this by running:

```
values & lengths >= 10
```

And finally, since we want to return a vector of the same lengths as `nrow(df)`, we use `rep(..., lengths)` and `as.integer` in order to return 1/0 instead of `TRUE`/`FALSE`.

Comment: The other two suggestions work too, but this was the simplest and I'm somehow inclined to use R-base solution if such exists. Thanks!

Comment: You may want to closely examine this solution.  I got dummy values = 1 on days 67-75, despite the fact that these days are not a part of a consecutive 10 day run of > 5 degree temps

Comment: @JHowIX, can you provide an example of that? Note that the sample data uses `rnorm` without setting a seed so solutions are not necessary the same (since sample data may differ)

Comment: @docendodiscimus - true, I am not sure how would like me to communicate sample data.  However, run your solution and my solution on the same dataframe, they produce different results, which means either yours or mine is incorrect.  If its mine I would like to know so I can correct it.

Comment: @JHowIX will do that when I get back to my desk

Comment: `rle`  <-- the closest `R` has to an all-purpose hammer.  :-)

Comment: @JHowIX, I just double checked with this sample data `set.seed(1); df <- data.frame(date = seq(365), temp = -30 + 0.65*seq(365) - 0.0018*seq(365)^2 + rnorm(365))` and comparing the results from your answer and mine I think your's is wrong. Did you compare your result to the OP's `df$dummyConditional` column? (It is identical with the dummy column created by my answer)

Answer (score 5):

I think you could use a combination of a simple ifelse and the roll apply function in the [zoo package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/zoo.pdf) to achieve what you are looking for.  The final step just involves padding the result to account for the first N-1 days where there isnt enough information to fill the window.

```
library(zoo)

df <- data.frame(date = seq(365), 
                 temp = -30 + 0.65*seq(365) - 0.0018*seq(365)^2 + rnorm(365))

df$above5 <- ifelse(df$temp > 5, 1, 0)
temp <- rollapply(df$above5, 10, sum)
df$conseq <- c(rep(0, 9),temp)
```

Comment: replace `function(x) { sum(x) }` with a simple `sum` ?

Comment: Suggest writing it like this: `df2 <- transform(transform(df, uncond = temp > 5),
     head = rollsum(uncond, 10, align = "left", fill = 0) == 10,
     tail = rollsum(uncond, 10, align = "right", fill = 0) == 10) + 0`

Answer (score 2):

I would do this:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(date = seq(365), 
                 temp = -30 + 0.65*seq(365) - 0.0018*seq(365)^2 + rnorm(365))
thr <- 5
df$dum <- 0

#find first 10 consecutive values above threshold
test1 <- filter(df$temp > thr, rep(1,10), sides = 1) == 10L
test1[1:9] <- FALSE
n <- which(cumsum(test1) == 1L)

#count days above threshold after that
df$dum[(n+1):nrow(df)] <- cumsum(df$temp[(n+1):nrow(df)] > thr)
```