# How to create a "conditional" variable in R?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, data.table

I want to create a conditional dummy variable. Assume that I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
Subject Year    X   X1
   A    1990    1   0
   A    1991    1   0
   A    1992    2   0
   A    1993    3   0
   A    1994    4   0
   A    1995    4   1
   B    1990    0   0
   B    1991    1   0
   B    1992    1   0
   B    1993    2   0
   B    1994    3   0
   C    1990    1   0
   C    1991    2   0
   C    1992    3   1
   C    1993    3   0
   D    1990    1   0
   D    1991    2   0
   D    1992    3   0
   D    1993    4   1
   D    1994    5   0
   E    1990    1   0
   E    1991    1   0
   E    1992    2   1
   E    1993    3   0
```

Let's call this conditional variable:*Q1to3_noX1*. Another variable of interest is *Q1to3*.

The *Q1to3* variable is also a dummy variable indicating 1 when the X has reached value 3, and 0 otherwise (for each Subject). If the X is 4 or more, then the *Q1to3* variable should be 0. The X is a cumulative variable (0,1,2,3,4...).  So in other words, the *Q1to3* is 1 if the maximum X value is 3.

I created this variable using: `data$Q1to3 <- ave(data$X, data$Subject, FUN = function(x) if (max(x) == 3) 1 else 0)` (thanks to @Zelazny7).

The *Q1to3_noX1* variable is very similar to the *Q1to3* variable, but in contrast to the *Q1to3* , it is conditional on the X1  variable. To be more precise, if the X1 = 1 in the following 5 years (counting from the first year of *Q1to3*), the *Q1to3_no5* should be 0. In other words, the *Q1to3_noX1* should be 1 if a)the maximum X value is 3, b) if X1=0 following 5 years(otherwise 0).

I understand from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35132812/how-to-create-a-conditional-dummy-in-r) that I should use the `rle`function. However, I haven't been able to apply it in this particular case. Do you have any suggestions?

The desirable outcome should look like this:

```
Subject Year    X   X1  Q1to3   Q1to3_noX1
   A    1990    1   0   0          0
   A    1991    1   0   0          0
   A    1992    2   0   0          0
   A    1993    3   0   0          0
   A    1994    4   0   0          0
   A    1995    4   1   0          0
   B    1990    0   0   1          0
   B    1991    1   0   1          1
   B    1992    1   0   1          1
   B    1993    2   0   1          1
   B    1994    3   0   1          1
   C    1990    1   0   1          0
   C    1991    2   0   1          0
   C    1992    3   1   1          0
   C    1993    3   0   1          0
   D    1990    1   0   0          0
   D    1991    2   0   0          0
   D    1992    3   0   0          0
   D    1993    4   1   0          0
   D    1994    5   0   0          0
   E    1990    1   0   1          0
   E    1991    1   0   1          0
   E    1992    2   1   1          0
   E    1993    3   0   1          0
```

A reproducible sample:

```
    > dput(data)
structure(list(Subject = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), class = "factor"), 
    Year = c(1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1990L, 
    1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1990L, 
    1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L), 
    X = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), X1 = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Q1to3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Q1to3_noX1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Subject", "Year", "X", "X1", "Q1to3", 
"Q1to3_noX1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

Comment: have you tried `mutate` from `dplyr` along with `ifelse`?

Comment: @JosephWood Hi! No, I haven't. Thanks, I'll look into it now

Comment: Should the row containing Subject B; year 1990, have a Q1to3 value = 1 instead of 0?

Comment: @JosephWood that's right, I'll correct right away

Comment: Here is a general idea using @Zelazny7 suggestion: `data$dummy <- ave(data$X1, data$Subject,  FUN = function(x) if (max(x) == 1) 1 else 0)` then using `dplyr` we have: `data %>% mutate(Q1to3_noX1 = ifelse(dummy==0 & Q1to3==1, 1, 0)) %>% select(-dummy)`

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
data$cX1 <- do.call("c",tapply(data$X1, data$Subject, FUN = function(x){
  nx=length(x) #i=1
  sx=c()
  if (nx<5) sx[1:nx]<-sum(x[1:nx]) else
  for(i in 1:nx)sx[i]<-sum(x[i:min(i+5-1,nx)])
  sx
},simplify = T))

data$Q1to3_noX1f2<-ifelse(data$Q1to3==1 & data$cX1==0,1,0)
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try this soon. I tried the previous version,  but it didn't really work the way I wanted. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example using Base R. I'm not 100% I understand the exact details of the question, but this pattern should solve your problem.

`ave` is great for broadcasting a summarized vector back to the original dimensions of the data. But if you look at the function body for `ave` it is just using `split` under the hood. We can do the same and create multiple columns per chunk instead of just one:

```
# split the data.frame
s <- split(df, df$Subject)

## calculate both columns at once per subject
both <- lapply(s, function(chunk) {
  Q1to3 <- if (max(chunk$X) == 3) 1 else 0
  Q1to3_noX1 <- if (Q1to3 == 1 & all(chunk$X1 == 0)) 1 else 0
  data.frame(Q1to3, Q1to3_noX1)
})

## cbind them back together and unsplit
out <- unsplit(Map(cbind, s, both), df$Subject)
```